# Change name of all elements in XML <element> to <ns2:element>

Tags: xml

I'm getting XML from webservice which looks like:

```
<CLASSXml>
    <CalculationIndex>
        <RunDesc>NormalCalc</RunDesc>
    </CalculationIndex>
    <GlobalData>
        <CalcIdent>
            <CalcUId>CLASS:20151203:19335012:000000000000:203:CS:CZK:349074</CalcUId>
            <CalcNo>2454307111</CalcNo>
            <CustomNo>349074</CustomNo>
            <CalcVer>2300</CalcVer>
            <XMLVer>23.00.01</XMLVer>
            <ClassBuild>23.00.04.03</ClassBuild>
            <SAXIFVersion>6.2</SAXIFVersion>
```

(it is much longer in real situation)

So in general it's on parent element with multiple childs and childs of childs.

I need to change name of each element in this XML like `<CalculationIndex>` or `<RunDesc>` or `<CLASSXml>` and so on and add ns2: before it so in this case `<ns2:CalculationIndex>` or `<ns2:RunDesc>` or `<ns2:CLASSXml>`

Is there a way how to foreach whole XML and edit name of each part between < > by adding some string before it?

Comment: Is there any reason to not simply set a default namespace for the root tag? something like: xmlns="http://xml.example.com/ns/library"

Comment: Why don't you just declare the namespace on the root element? (assuming it is for the whole file) The namespace prefix to an element is arbitrary.

Comment: XML I'm getting is from webservice, I dont have access to change data which comes from there.

@SamuelÅslund your advise looks really clever, can you provide some example code please?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp   I have heard that they are not always 100% accurate but most of the time they are good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to use `str_replace` to change the required elements:

```
$xml = str_replace('<CalculationIndex>', '<ns2:CalculationIndex>', $xml);
$xml = str_replace('</CalculationIndex>', '</ns2:CalculationIndex>', $xml);
// etc.
```

Edit: or if there are many elements, you could use a regular expression:

```
$xml = preg_replace('/<(.+)>/', '<ns2:$1>', $xml);
$xml = preg_replace('/<\/(.+)>/', '</ns2:$1>', $xml);
```

Comment: Hey @this. lau i agree this is simple and can be helpfull but this will change just elements i specify, i there a way how to do it for all of them?

Comment: @Andurit, you could use a regular expression (see updated answer).

Comment: The above suggestion of text replacement will not work for all cases; specifically it does not handle attributes on elements.  If XML is handled as raw text it needs to be treated with caution.  I would recommend processing any XML changes as XML.

Comment: @Paul, yes it depends on his use case. If it looks like the XML he posted, then this solution would work. If it's more complicated it might indeed be better to parse it properly.